# UIView subclass dealloc not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting, aqgridview

I am using AQGridView for displaying a grid of images in my app. A user clicks on an album and then I open a new controller with the grid that has all the images. The problem is that the when the user presses the back button to go back to the list of albums, the dealloc on the grid view is not getting called. I have logged a string in dealloc of my view controller and it is being called. 
I have checked the heapshots in Instruments and everything related to AQGridView is not deallocated even after the view is popped. I use Interface Builder to create the grid view and it is connected to grid view in my .h file.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet AQGridView *gridView;
```

I am not holding any other pointers to the grid view. I am using ARC for the project. Do I need to deallocate the gridView somehow in the grid view controller's dealloc or is it handled automatically by ARC? If it is, what might be preventing it from being deallocated?

EDIT:
I am using NSOperationQueue to load the images in the background and then after the images are loaded, I put them in grid cells.

Comment: I'd rather use strong than weak for that type.

Comment: Check Allocations in instruments, find your object and see what has incremented it's retain count to check if you've missed something

Comment: @ott-- I have tried using strong too. No changes.

Comment: Put the `self.gridView = nil;` into the `viewDidUnload` method. And for `weak` and `strong`: see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html the paragraph `ARC Introduces New Lifetime Qualifiers`.

Comment: @ott-- I am now using strong for gridView and doing `self.gridView = nil;` in `viewDidUnload`. Grid view is still not deallocated. Btw, `viewDidUnload` is not being called when I press Back button.

Comment: Ok, the right method would be `viewWillDisappear:`. Don't forget the `[super viewWillDisappear:];`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but it sill doesn't work. `viewWillDisappear` gets called but setting it to nil doesn't call the view's dealloc.

Comment: @ott-- If it makes any difference, I am also using multiple threads to load images in the background and then add them into the grid cells.

Comment: With ARC you don't the dealloc anymore. Setting the view to nil is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In the `dealloc` method of your grid view controller, set the gridView pointer to nil.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    self.gridView = nil; 
}
```

Comment: If you are using ARC you don't call super's dealloc explicitly - it is added automatically by the compiler for you.  The OP stated he is using ARC, but you are correct, in a non-ARC project (only) you should include a call to [super dealloc]. (reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW14)

Comment: @jonkroll Doesn't change anything. dealloc is still not called.